# Can't login to openshift from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, openshift

I have created OpenShift account, and I can login to OpenShift web console from browser,  but I can't connect from eclipse. Server type is set to OpenShift 2 and "use default server" is checked. I entered the email address for username and password, the same stuff I use for logging in on OpenShift Web Console.

When I try to login I get :

`Your credentials are not authorized to access "https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/user"`

Comment: When you login to the web console, what URL do you login to?

Comment: @WillGordon
First I go to https://manage.openshift.com/ and then login with red hat which takes me to https://developers.redhat.com/auth/realms/rhd/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=oso&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmanage.openshift.com%2Faccounts%2Fauth%2Fkeycloak%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=openid+profile+email&state=2f7332d125be70a47091b7b423e74249

Comment: Ok, that helps. The problem you're running into is that you're actually using OpenShift Online 3. You can find a blog post about using eclipse with OpenShift Online 3 [here](https://blog.openshift.com/getting-started-eclipse-jboss-tools-openshift-online-3/). The only difference being that you need to replace the *console* url with the correct url from your cluster.

Comment: @WillGordon
Thanks a lot, that solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that you're actually using OpenShift Online 3. You can find a blog post about using eclipse with OpenShift Online 3 [here](https://blog.openshift.com/getting-started-eclipse-jboss-tools-openshift-online-3/). The only difference being that you need to replace the console url with the correct url from your cluster.

Your cluster's console URL will look like `https://console.<cluster-name>.openshift.com`.